# How to localize the password reset email sent with firebase in unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Firebase is great and it is quite easy to set up an email authentication with it in unity and even to send a password reset email.
However, I cannot figure out how to set the email language.

In Java for android the code is:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.setLanguageCode("fr");
// or auth.useAppLanguage();
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail("mymail@me.com")
```

But I cannot find the equivalent in the c# SDK for unity.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
auth.setLanguageCode("fr"); // this methode doesn't exist
auth.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync("mymail@me.com");
```

Comment: Somehow I as User/Developer would expect it is automatically localized with the language a user configured for him/herself, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this API call is not yet implemented in the C++ or Unity SDKs.

I've made sure that there's a [feature request filed](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) to update the SDK, but until then see if this works as a workaround (I don't have a project I can verify with right now):

```
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetLanguageCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _languageCode;

    void Start()
    {
        // make sure auth is initialized via Unity/C++ before invoking JNI calls
        var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        var authClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth");
        var authInstance = authClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("DefaultInstance");
        authInstance.Call("setLanguageCode", _languageCode);
        Debug.Log($"Set language code to {_languageCode}");
    }
}
```

I verify that the auth singleton is initialized with the `var auth =` line. Then I try to use Unity's JNI interop functionality to retrieve the singleton on the Java side and invoke the missing method directly.

Comment: I've tried your solution in the unity editor (with the Android platform selected), and when I debug it, the authClass is correctly set, but the authInstance is null, thus the language is not changed. Do you know why?

Comment: Oh no, that's a bit surprising. Is `auth` non-null?

Comment: Yes, `auth` is not null, and is even used before. I tried building just in case, but it doesn't work either